# how to loop images by names and numbers?

Tags: image, loops, loading

```
<div>
<a><img src="../photos/vacances01.jpg"></a>
</div>
<div>
<a><img src="../photos/vacances02.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

i would like to create a loop to read all the images in the file called  vacances01, vacances02...
and famille01, famille02...

with for exemple the possibility to defina a part the word "vacances", or "famille", or "cars"....

like i specify a word which go after '../photos/' then it loops the numbers with 'i++' and it write at the end '.jpg'

and it generate that in loops :

```
<div>
<a><img src="../photos/vacances01.jpg"></a>
</div>
...
```

do you understand me ?
thank you in advance, my level is not very high

Answer (score 1):

First of you have to understand that HTML is not a programming language in the way you think it is. HTML is, as the name suggests, a markup lanuage, used for designing websites. The "i++" is used in languages like C++ and Java. JavaScript could be used for such a task. How, I do not know.

Comment: yes sorry, i know it is javascript... i was not clear in my question you are right.